# JavaScript bind event to array of buttons

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I try to create array of buttons, bind click event and push variable "editor" to callback function;

```
  buttons = {
    save:{
      name:  "save",
      title: "save",
      action: function(editor) { alert('Save cliked.'); console.log(editor);}
    },
    preview:{
      name:  "preview",
      title: "preview",
      action: function(editor) { alert("Preview clicked."); console.log(editor);}
    },
    format:{
      name:  "format",
      title: "format",
      action: function(editor) { alert('Format clicked.'); console.log(editor);}
    }
  };


  for (var key in buttons) {
    butHash = buttons[key];
    var button = panel.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    button.setAttribute("title", butHash.title);
    button.setAttribute("class", "cm-panel-button " + butHash.name);
    button.textContent = "";
    console.log(button);
    editor = "some editor instance"
    $(button).on('click', function(){
      console.log(butHash.name);
      butHash.action(editor);
    });
  };
```

When I click to any of this buttons I always see last callback "Format clicked".
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript closures :) Your code is fine, you just need to move the inside of the for loop into a separate function to create a new scope since in Javascript, closures are created on a function level, not block level.

```
for(var key in buttons){
  createButton(key);
}

function createButton(key){
  var butHash = buttons[key]
  ...
}
```

... that should do it.

If you want to read more on closures, I reccomend e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue) or possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save second half of my day. :-)

Comment: You are very welcome :) If you have the time, check out the links attached since it is definitely worth making sure that you understand how closures in Javascript work.